# What error this points to - "new_window_surface returns 0x3000"

Tags: android, android-activity

In my activity, I want to create an independent surface (not linked to existing activity window) and show some content in it. I mean this window should come on top of my existing activity window).

When I try that, I get this message in logcat:

> D/mali_winsys(  119): new_window_surface returns 0x3000

And my window is not seen. Can someone help me by telling if this message points to some error?

I am trying it on 4.4.2 (Nexus 10 tablet)

Answer (score 12):

This is not an error. I just spent the last hour trying to find out what the message means, and discovered in egl.h that 0x3000 is the return code for EGL_SUCCESS. So the message is just saying that the attempt to get a new window surface was successful.

Comment: Whenever I tried to update the shader argument values, This log message come in logcat. This this creating a new surface while just changing the shader values? Does it impact of the performance of GL on GPU?